# AR Android Sceneform SDK display model only on the floor

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform, 3d-model

I'm using Sceneform SDK for Android version

```
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.15.0'
```

I need my 3D model to be displayed only on the floor. For example I have a 3D cage (simple transparent cuboid) and I need to place this 3D model over real object. For now if my real object has enough big surface the model will be placed at the top of it instead of go over it and I need to avoid behavior.
[image]

Here is some code here.

Logic to init ArFragment and display model at the center of the camera. I'm making a HitTest at the center of the my device camera any time when frame is changed.

```
private fun initArFragment() {
    arFragment.arSceneView.scene.addOnUpdateListener {
        arFragment.arSceneView?.let { sceneView ->
            sceneView.arFrame?.let { frame ->
                if (frame.camera.trackingState == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                    val hitTest =
                        frame.hitTest(sceneView.width / 2f, sceneView.height / 2f)
                    val hitTestIterator = hitTest.iterator()
                    if (hitTestIterator.hasNext()) {
                            val hitResult = hitTestIterator.next()
                            val anchor = hitResult.createAnchor()
                            if (anchorNode == null) {
                                anchorNode = AnchorNode()
                                anchorNode?.setParent(sceneView.scene)
                                transformableNode =
                                    DragTransformableNode(arFragment.transformationSystem)
                                transformableNode?.setParent(anchorNode)
                                boxNode = createBoxNode(.4f, .6f, .4f) // Creating cuboid 
                                boxNode?.setParent(transformableNode)
                            }
                            anchorNode?.anchor?.detach()
                            anchorNode?.anchor = anchor
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's expected behavior because HitTest hits on the surface of real object as well. But Don't know how to avoid this behavior.
Is there a way to ignore real objects and place 3D model always at the floor?

**UPDATE**
I tried to follow @Mick suggestions. I'm trying to group all HitTestResult. When HitTest is done I get list a of all HitResults for all visible planes. I'm grouping them by its rounded Y axis.
*Example*
{1.35 -> [Y is 1.36776767, Y is 1.35434343, Y is 1.35999999, Y is 1.37723278]}
{1.40 -> [Y is 1.4121212, Y is 1.403232323, Y is 1.44454545, Y is 1.40001011]}
Then for X and Z anchor points I'm using FIRST HitResult with from array sorted keys from MIN to MAX key in the example it's 1.35.
For Y anchor point I'm getting array of a MIN group elements and get it's average value.

```
 val hitResultList = hitTestIterator.asSequence().toList().groupBy { round(it.hitPose.ty() * 20) / 20 }.minBy { it.key }?.value
 val hitResult = hitResultList?.first()!!
 val averageValueOfY = hitResultList?.map { it.hitPose.ty() }?.average()
 createModel(hitResult, averageValueOfY)
```

Method to create Model

```
private fun createModel(newHitResult: HitResult, averageValueOfY: Double) {
    try {
        val newAnchorPose = newHitResult.createAnchor().pose
        anchorNode?.anchor?.detach()
        anchorNode?.anchor = arFragment.arSceneView.session?.createAnchor(Pose(floatArrayOf(newAnchorPose.tx(),
                averageValueOfY.toFloat(), newAnchorPose.tz()), floatArrayOf(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)))
        isArBagModelRendered = true
        transformableNode?.select()
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Timber.d(exception)
    }
}
```

This code update helped to get the behaviour which I tried to achieve, **but** I noticed that sometimes my Y anchor point is underground it looks like MIN plane was detected under the floor :( and I don't know how to fix this issue for now.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think you possibly have two separate problems you will face for your use case:

- object being placed on the top surface as you have highlighted in the question
- Occlusion, or not showing the part of the model that should be hidden behind the object, when the model is actually put in the correct place.

A simple solution to the first problem so you can check the second, or maybe more accurately a workaround, might be to simply get the user to place the object in front of the real object, i.e. the case in your example above, and then move it back until it is exactly where they want it.

If you leave the plane highlighting on, i.e. the grid lines which show where a plane is detected, it may be more intuitive for a user to 'hit' the floor also rather than the top of the object.

This would allow you test quickly if the occlusion issue is actually the more serious issue, before you go too much further.

A more complex solution would be to iterate through the planes and experiment with comparing the 'pose' at the centre of each plane to see if you can find reliable way to decide which is the floor - the method is part of the Plane class:

> public Pose getCenterPose ()

> Returns the pose of the center of the detected plane. The pose's transformed +Y axis will be point normal out of the plane, with the +X and +Z axes orienting the extents of the bounding rectangle.

There are also methods to get the size of the width or depth of the plane if you were sure the floor will always be the biggest plane:

> public float getExtentX ()

> Returns the length of this plane's bounding rectangle measured along the local X-axis of the coordinate space centered on the plane.

> public float getExtentZ ()

> Returns the length of this plane's bounding rectangle measured along the local Z-axis of the coordinate frame centered on the plane.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any existing handy help function like 'get lowest plane', or get 'largest plane' etc.

Note on the occlusion issue, there are frameworks and libraries that do provide some forms of software based occlusion, i.e. without requiring the device to have extra depth sensors, so it may be worth exploring these a little also.